# Cambiar iconos a la hora de trazar una ruta en Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova

Tengo una función que traza una ruta entre 2 puntos, pero en los iconos coloca punto a y punto b. Requiero cambiar el icono de origen y de destino.

Comment: Tienes la respuesta en este [enlace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5199909/7002158). Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

El constructor de Marker recibe dentro de las configuraciones icon en el cual puedes especificar una imagen de icono. Ej:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    position: feature.position,
    icon: 'http://es.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-Pink-icon.png',
    map: map
});
```

Comment: Si pero me sigue saliendo el punto A, por debajo de mi icono

Comment: Ya lo termine, faltaban algunas cosas mas para que cambiara el icono.

Comment: @WilmerMorgado por favor comparte lo que faltaba puede ser de ayuda para alguien mas.

Comment: Faltaba agregar esto: suppressMarkers: true. Dentro de var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();. Quedando de la siguiente manera: var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});

Comment: Espero le sea de ayuda